# Images of basal cell carcinomas (BCC) annotated with the BCC type (Superficial, Nodular, Pigmented, Morpheaform / Infiltrating, etc.)

Tags: data-request, medical, images

I am looking for a dataset containing images of basal cell carcinomas (BCC) annotated with the BCC type (Superficial, Nodular, Pigmented, Morpheaform / Infiltrating, etc.) and ideally some image segmentation indicating where the BCC is on the image.

https://skinio.com/education/basal-cell-carcinoma/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201120235927/https://skinio.com/education/basal-cell-carcinoma/)) presents the main 4 types of BCC:

[image]

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.